# Different results for same argument for different Unix functions

Tags: bash, wildcard, ls, md5sum

I am getting somewhat different results with using these commands:

```
ls "$MYDIR/*.avi"
md5sum "$MYDIR/*.avi"
```

using win-bash. The former lists only the files that end with .avi while the latter does the checksum calculation for all files containing .avi. Is this expected? I thought the wildcard operation should work the same throughout.

Comment: Can you review your post again and correct formatting around `ls` and `md5sum` commands?  In Stack Overflow, "verbatim" (aka "code" or "pre-formatted") texts should be enclosed with backticks.  I can directly edit your post but am wondering how I should do because there's someting wrong with the number of double quotes in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're quoting the wildcard, it is not being expanded by the shell (but the variable is). That means you're letting the command decide what to do with the `*` character.

You  want the shell to expand the filenames before invoking the command:

```
ls "$MYDIR"/*.avi
md5sum "$MYDIR"/*.avi
```

You might want to store the results in an array if you're reusing them

```
files=( "$MYDIR"/*.avi )
ls "${files[@]}"
md5sum "${files[@]}"
```